# A question regarding algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A book costs $1$ plus half its price. How much does it cost?

The answer to the question as suggested by some is $2$.

They equated this by taking a variable for price and forming a linear equation:

$$p=1+p/2\\p=2$$

I think there is some problem in this answer but I am not getting what it actually is.

Comment: If the price really were \$2, how much would be \$1 plus half the price?

Comment: I don't see a problem with the answer.

Comment: $p=1+p/2$ implies $p-p/2=1$ implies $p(1-1/2)=1$ implies $p=1/(1/2)=2$. nothing wrong here.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you think there's a problem in this answer?

Comment: Somebody subscribes to Presh's channel.

Answer (score 1):

If p is its price then

p/2 is "half-its-price".

So 1+p/2 is 1+"half-its-price", which is assumed to be  its cost,

which is its price, which is p.

So 1+p/2=p.

Unless you are an accountant, who would object to using "price" and "cost" synonymously.